# match, iterate, create and create relationship assistance

Tags: cypher

Using this pseudo code,  how can I do this entirely in cypher?

match-all nodes with the property of `type: Images`

*using properties from the original match*

match using the properties from the main match for `type: Parent` nodes

if no nodes of the parameters with the `type: Parent`
create a new node using the parameters and `type: Parent`

match using the properties from the main match for `type: Parent` nodes

create a parent -> image relationship, using the node from the initial match and the match for `type: Parent` node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MATCH (img:Images)   //matches all nodes with the label Images
WITH img             //carries forward the matched img nodes to the next clause.
MERGE (parent:Parent {property1: img.property1, property2: img.property2, ...})  // finds or creates a Parent node with the properties taken from the matched img nodes. Replace property1, property2, etc., with the actual property names you want to use.
MERGE (parent)-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->(img)  //finds or creates a relationship between the parent node and the img node. Replace RELATIONSHIP_TYPE with the actual relationship type you want to use.
```